# Bound of an integral of a bounded function

Tags: calculus, integration

If a function $f$ is bounded such that $|f|<M$, then can we say:
$$ \left|\int_a^ \infty f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \right| \le \int_a^ \infty  |f(x)| \,\mathrm{d}x  \le  \int_a^ \infty M\, \mathrm{d}x$$
Is that correct?

Thank you!

Comment: But the last expression is just $\infty$ and the inequity does not provide useful information, I think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct.

Since $ -|f| \leq f \leq |f|$:
$$
-\int_a^\infty |f(x)|\,dx\leq \int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx \leq \int_a^\infty |f(x)| \,dx \\
\therefore \left| \int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx \right| \leq \int_a^\infty|f(x)| \,dx
$$
The right one easily follows from the precondition.

$$
|f(x)| < M \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq M \\
\int_a^\infty |f(x)|\, dx \leq \int_a^\infty M\,dx
$$

Combine these two to get your desired inequality.

Comment: Suppose that we have a function $f=2$ which is surely bounded with a boundary $M\ge 2$,  now we integrate $f$ over the interval $[a,\infty)$, which gives us infinity, i.e., the integral is not bounded. The problem in your proof is that the interval of integration is infinite.